# "Most wild thing I have ever done" - grammaticality

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to say "most wild thing I have ever done"?

I know it doesn't sound appropriate but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, the statement is entirely, 100 percent, correct. Please tell us why you think it doesn't sound appropriate.

Comment: @OliverMason Obviously because the superlative is "wildest" not *"most wild".

Comment: @vth Obviously because the superlative is "wildest" not *"most wild".

Comment: Could have sworn that the question said *wildest* instead of *the most wild*. Hmm. Nevertheless, although *the most wild thing* doesn't sound very natural, it is grammatically correct. In fact, it is regularly used by National Geographic - example: https://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/photography/photos-worlds-most-beautiful-places/

Comment: @Kris Yes, *I* know that... :)

Comment: @vth That's *not* the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps sounds inappropriate to you because the most commonly used superlative form of *wild* is *wildest*: ‘It was the wildest thing I have ever done.’

This is because to form a superlative from one syllable adjectives you generally add the suffix *-est.*

You would also add *-est* to two syllable words that end in 'y' or 'ly': *happy* becomes *happiest* and *early* becomes *earliest*.

But for many two syllables adjectives the superlative is formed by putting *most* first: *most famous*.

The superlative of adjectives with three or more syllables is also formed by putting *most* first.

It is worth noting there are also some irregular superlatives such as *bad* becoming  *worst*.

Comment: Please note that the search will not be very accurate. Most wild google searches produce false positives, as do most wild goose chases. That is because they disregard the context in which the phrase is used.

Comment: You're right. I will edit my post to remove that citation. 'Most' could also appear next to 'wild' as a determiner rather than an adverb: e.g. 'Most wild game animals are lean.'

Comment: Even the ***unfriendliest*** of alleged rules has counterexamples that put the lie to it.

Comment: I was trying to suggest that these are patterns of usage rather than definitive rules.